# Best way to add meta information to the XML document

Tags: xml

I have tabular data, called `Person`, for example. The column headers are `email`, `fname`, `lname` and `ssn`. I came with the following XML structure:

```
<object type="Person">
  <record>
    <property name="email" val="mrnt..."/>
    <property name="fname" val="Martin"/>
    <property name="lname" val="Dimitrov"/>
    <property name="ssn" val="123"/>
  </record>
  <record>
    <property name="email" val="dani..."/>
    <property name="fname" val="Dany"/>
    <property name="lname" val="Jones"/>
    <property name="ssn" val="987"/>
  </record>
</object>
```

So far so good but there are some rules I have to follow:

1. The table can be with no rows and I still have to provide its structure;
2. A column might be completely empty but I still have to include its name in the meta description of the table
3. `email` and `ssn` are unique columns and I have to indicate that somehow.

So what is the best way to include the meta description of the table? Is this OK? Seems a little odd to me.

```
<object type="Person">
  <model>
    <property name="email" unique="yes"/>
    <property name="fname"/>
    <property name="lname"/>
    <property name="ssn" unique="yes"/>
  </model>
  <record>
    <property name="email" val="mrnt..."/>
    <property name="fname" val="Martin"/>
    <property name="lname" val="Dimitrov"/>
    <property name="ssn" val="123"/>
  </record>
  <record>
    <property name="email" val="dani..."/>
    <property name="fname" val="Dany"/>
    <property name="lname" val="Jones"/>
    <property name="ssn" val="987"/>
  </record>
</object>
```

Please, note, the column headers can have any values. They might not be only four as well.

Comment: If the table has relationships to other tables, simple key/value won't work, unless the table completely flat with no relations to other tables; this is for one table only, `Person`?

Comment: It is completely flat, I only wonder how to describe its structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have presented it this way :

```
<root>
  <person>
    <email/>
    <fname/>
    <lname/>
    <ssn/>
  </person>
  <person>
    <email>mrnt...</email>
    <fname>Martin</fname>
    <lname>Dimitrov</lname>
    <ssn>123</ssn>
  </person>
  <person>
    <email>dani...</email>
    <fname>Dany</fname>
    <lname>Jones</lname>
    <ssn>987</ssn>
  </person>
</root>
```

And associate an xsd schema defining the maxoccurs attribute of email and ssd to 1

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="person">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="email" maxOccurs="1"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="fname"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="lname"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="ssn" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where in your opinion should I add the `unique` attribute?

Comment: The 'unique' attribute is handled by the 'maxOccurs="1"' in the xsd. You can see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_indicators.asp) for the documentation about this.

Answer (score 1):

Use XSD to describe document structure and element constraints; don't embed metadata in the document itself.

With XSD, you can validate the document against its schema; if you embed metadata describing constraints inside the document, you have to validate it manually, creating more work; new constraints mean updating your code. With XSD, it's handled automatically via the schema.

Comment: Please, note, that the column headers can hold any value.